# How to index a dataframe using a condition on a column that is a column of numpy arrays?

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a pandas dataframe that has a column of values that are numpy arrays. I am trying to get the rows of the dataframe where the value of the column is an empty numpy array but I can't index using the pandas method.
Here is an example dataframe.

```
data = {'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'stats': [np.array([1,1,1]), np.array([]), np.array([2,2,2]), np.array([])]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I am trying to just get the rows where 'stats' is None, but when I try `df[df['stats'] is None]` I just get a KeyError: False.
How can I filter by rows that contain an empty list?

Additionally, how can I filter by row where the numpy array is something specific? i.e. get all rows of df where df['stats'] == np.array([1, 1, 1])

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check length by [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html), because it working with all Iterables:

```
print (df['stats'].str.len())
0    3
1    0
2    3
3    0
Name: stats, dtype: int64
```

And then filter, e.g. rows with `len=0`:

```
df = df[df['stats'].str.len().eq(0)]
#alternative
#df = df[df['stats'].apply(len).eq(0)]
print (df)
  Name stats
1    B    []
3    D    []
```

If need test specific array is possible use `tuple`s:

```
df =df[ df['stats'].apply(tuple) == tuple(np.array([1, 1, 1]))]
print (df)
  Name      stats
0    A  [1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much. Just one more thing how would I check if the numpy array is something specific i.e. get all rows of df where df['stats'] == np.array([1, 1, 1])

Comment: @Anonymous
Answered your second question as another answer.

Answer (score 1):

for this question:
"Additionally, how can I filter by row where the numpy array is something specific? i.e. get all rows of df where df['stats'] == np.array([1, 1, 1])"

```
data = {'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'stats': [np.array([1,1,1]), np.array([]), np.array([2,2,2]), np.array([])]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df[df['stats'].apply(lambda x: np.array_equal(x, np.array([1,1,1])))]
```